# Parse just url, based on link declaration in beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Im trying to ultimately just `parse` out the `url` out of a page, if it meets a certain condition where one of the keywords in `xx_web_job_alt_keywords` is in the text of `job.get_text()` .

```
xx_good_jobs = []
xx_web_job_alt_keywords = ['Website']
# <a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/123.html" data-id="5966181668">Print business magazine's website management</a>
each_job_link_details = soup.find_all('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')

for job in each_job_link_details:
    if xx_web_job_alt_keywords in job.get_text():
        #append '//mywebsite.com/web/123.html' to list:xx_good_jobs 
        xx_good_jobs.append(xx_web_job_alt_keywords.get('href',None))
```

How does this look to you?

Comment: What is the actual problem? All these xx_es hurt my eyes =(

Comment: I had mentioned: Im looking to get a bunch of links from this site with characteristics of links `a`, with class `result-title hdrlnk`. Then look at just the `text` of the link e.g. `<a somelink attributes>TEXT</a> if it contains any word from `xx_web_job_alt_keywords` then put it in a list named: `xx_good_jobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4, re
#keywords = ['Website', 'Website', 'business']
html = '''<a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/123.html" data-id="5966181668">Print business magazine's website management</a>
        <a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/123.html" data-id="5966181668">Print business magazine's website management</a>
        <a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/123.html" data-id="5966181668">Print business magazine's website management</a>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

keywords = ['Website', 'Website', 'business']
regex = '|'.join(keywords)
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk", text=re.compile(regex,re.IGNORECASE)):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

out:

```
//mywebsite.com/web/123.html
//mywebsite.com/web/123.html
//mywebsite.com/web/123.html
```

EDIT:

```
keywords = ['Website', 'Website', 'business']

regex = '|'.join(keywords)
```

out:

```
'Website|Website|business'
```

just use [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) and `|` to match multiple keyword in the a tag.

EDIT2:

```
keyword_lists = [['Website', 'Website', 'business'], ['Website1', 'Website1', 'business1'], ['Website2', 'Website2', 'business2']]
sum(keyword_lists, [])
```

out:

```
['Website',
 'Website',
 'business',
 'Website1',
 'Website1',
 'business1',
 'Website2',
 'Website2',
 'business2']
```

Comment: Lets just say there are more than a few keywords, could you use a list here? Maybe you could show that?

Comment: @Jshee sure, you can join the list of keywords into a regex string: `'|'.join(xx_web_job_alt_keywords)`.

Comment: Can you add that to your solution please? I really like your elegant solution

Comment: @Jshee `join` the list and put it in the `re.compile()`

Comment: Im a bit confused where I should add them in `re.compile`

Comment: Can you add multiple lists to your `join()` above, or should I use `.extend()`?

Comment: I will definitely accept yours, and thank you for your help. How is `keywords_lists` ever included in your final code? Does that just replace: `regex` in `re.compile(` ?

Comment: @Jshee it's an example, have nothing to do with my code.

Comment: could `join()` just include multiple `list`s like `.join(keywords, keywords2)`?

Comment: @Jshee no, see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: If you can please just show me how to join multiple lists here, instead of one on the `re.compile` please?

Comment: @Jshee I post every thing you need, the rest is on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can go with a more explicit approach using a  [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
xx_web_job_alt_keywords = ['Website']

def desired_links(tag):
    """Filters 'header' links having desired keywords in the text."""

    class_attribute = tag.get('class', [])
    is_header_link = tag.name == 'a' and 'result-title' in class_attribute and 'hdrlnk' in class_attribute

    link_text = tag.get_text()
    has_keywords = any(keyword.lower() in link_text.lower() for keyword in xx_web_job_alt_keywords)

    return is_header_link and has_keywords

xx_good_jobs = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all(desired_links)]
```

Note that we are using [`any()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any of the keywords is in the text. Also, note that we are *lowering* both the keyword and the text to handle differences in cases.

Demo:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """
   ...:     <div>
   ...:         <a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/123.html" data-id="596618166
   ...: 8">Print business magazine's website management</a>
   ...:         <a class="result-title hdrlnk" href="//mywebsite.com/web/456.html" data-id="1234">Som
   ...: e other header link</a>
   ...:     </div>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: xx_web_job_alt_keywords = ['Website']

In [5]: def desired_links(tag):
   ...:     """Filters 'header' links having desired keywords in the text."""
   ...: 
   ...:     class_attribute = tag.get('class', [])
   ...:     is_header_link = tag.name == 'a' and 'result-title' in class_attribute and 'hdrlnk' in cl
   ...: ass_attribute
   ...: 
   ...:     link_text = tag.get_text()
   ...:     has_keywords = any(keyword.lower() in link_text.lower() for keyword in xx_web_job_alt_key
   ...: words)
   ...: 
   ...:     return is_header_link and has_keywords
   ...: 

In [6]: xx_good_jobs = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all(desired_links)]

In [7]: xx_good_jobs
Out[7]: [u'//mywebsite.com/web/123.html']
```